# Eigen space and column space of matrix A is same?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let we have $n \times n$ matrix A with full rank.

Eigen vectors of A is in the column space of A, because eigen vector is made by linear combination of column vectors of A.

And, eigen vector also span the eigen space with same dimenson of column space of A.

So, I wonder whether the column space of A is equal to eigen space of A.

Comment: Note that the column space of $A$ is $K^n$, since your matrix has full rank. Now, its eigenspaces sum up to $K^n$ if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. Take, for instance, $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. It has full rank, but the column space is $\mathbb R^2$, whereas the only eigenspace is $\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb R\}$.